# Creating JSON representation from Go struct

Tags: json, go

I am trying to create a JSON string from a struct:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type CommentResp struct {
        Id   string `json: "id"`
        Name string `json: "name"`
    }

    stringa := CommentResp{
        Id:   "42",
        Name: "Foo",
    }

    fmt.Println(stringa)
}
```

This code prints `{42 foo}`, but I expected `{"Id":"42","Name":"Foo"}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are printing is `fmt`'s serialization of the `CommentResp` struct. Instead, you want to do is use [`json.Marshal`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshal) to get the encoded JSON repsentation:

```
data, err := json.Marshal(stringa)
if err != nil {
     // Problem encoding stringa
     panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ogWKQ3M6tb

Also, your `json` struct tags are not valid; there cannot be a space between `:` and the quoted string:

```
type CommentResp struct {
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eQiyTk6-vQ